# With stripe, is it possible to create a subscription 'on hold' and activate it on demand?

Tags: stripe-payments

I have an app with user authentication and subscriptions (monthly recurring).

My users are getting reviewed before they are entering the app and getting full access.
So it is necessary that the payment will be processed only after the admin has activated the user.

Is it possible to collect the user's payment details on registration , but hold the payment after user's confirmation?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is:

1. Collect your customer's payment method using [SetupIntents with Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse?platform=web&ui=checkout) or [Stripe Element](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse?platform=web&ui=elements)
2. The Admin reviews the customer
3. Once validated, You create the Subscription for the customer and use the PaymentMethod Id previously collected as a [default payment method](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-default_payment_method)